# This file was generated by an older version of protoc

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Running Ubuntu 16.04 and Gazebo 7. All works ok but then i installed cartographer.

As you can see from installation script (https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it installs protoc 3.4.1.
And now my project can not be build:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/msgs/MessageTypes.hh:91:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh:24,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/physics/Entity.hh:28,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/physics/Model.hh:32,
                 from /home/thesis/gazebo_animate_pose/animate_pose.cc:4:
/usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/msgs/wrench_stamped.pb.h:17:2: error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
/usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/msgs/wrench_stamped.pb.h:18:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
/usr/include/gazebo7/gazebo/msgs/wrench_stamped.pb.h:19:2: error: #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
```

I tried to install gazebo from source, but got another(seems related) problem:

```
/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.a(code_generator.cc.o): In function `google::protobuf::compiler::GeneratorContext::GetCompilerVersion(google::protobuf::compiler::Version*) const':
code_generator.cc:(.text+0x4e5): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.a(code_generator.cc.o): In function `google::protobuf::compiler::ParseGeneratorParameter(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >*)':
code_generator.cc:(.text+0x5fd): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::SplitStringUsing(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*)'
/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.a(plugin.cc.o): In function `google::protobuf::compiler::GenerateCode(google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGeneratorRequest const&, google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator const&, google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGeneratorResponse*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
plugin.cc:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::DescriptorPool()'.........
```

ps. yes, the problem is old (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4733/this-file-was-generated-by-an-older-version-of-protoc-while-following-gazebo-tutorial/), but i can not find solution - i want to use both gazebo and cartographer (or at least repaire gazebo).

Does gazebo can be build with protoc 3.4.1 ? How to do that? Or at least how to remove protoc 3.4 and how to work with cartographer? Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18096/this-file-was-generated-by-an-older-version-of-protoc/) by [l1va](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4227/l1va/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo is built against the version of `protoc` released to the ubuntu repos. On 16.04 that version is [2.6.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/protobuf/2.6.1-1.3).

There is no guarantee it will work using the newer protobuf version, but you can try building gazebo from source following this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install

The cartographer instructions install protobuf system wide using the script here: https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer/blob/master/scripts/install_proto3.sh . If building gazebo from source doesn't work then I recommend opening an issue on the cartographer repo asking how to build and run it without installing proto3 system wide.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l1va](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4227/l1va/) on 2017-12-13**:
Thanks for the answer.
I know these all and tried installing from source as i wrote - is not working.
Yes, i asked to help cartographer guys too, by commits - seems not so long time ago cartographer used protoc2.

**Comment by [lianghu3124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6400/lianghu3124/) on 2018-08-30**:
I met the same problem. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've come across to the same problem. I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`, `ROS Kinetic` and `Gazebo 7.0`.

First, be sure that you're using the `protoc` with a version above `2.6.1`. Gazebo 7 works along with the  `protoc-2.6.1`.
You can learn the version of the `protoc` installed on your system with `$ protoc --version` command. It was `3.2.0` in my system. Thus this solution replaces the `protobuf` installed on your system with the version `2.6.1`.

I solved the problem via using the following instructions.

1. `$ cd /usr/local/include/google`
2. `sudo rm -rf protobuf`
3. Go, download `protobuf-2.6.1` from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases?after=v3.0.0-alpha-1) and extract the contents. (I downloaded `protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz`)
4. I followed the installation instructions given [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src). Which are:

`$ ./autogen.sh`

`$ ./configure`

`$ make`

`$ make check`

`$ sudo make install`

`$ sudo ldconfig`

5. Right now I'm able to compile my workspace without a problem.

---

Originally posted by [MBD](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6443/mbd/) with karma: 11 on 2018-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bogga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7256/bogga/) on 2018-11-14**:
Thank you! This worked for me aswell! Saved me a good chunk of time! :D

**Comment by [RoboManiac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28759/robomaniac/) on 2020-07-06**:
Thanks, it worked for me. For those who are facing similar problems with gazebo 9 should use `protobuf-3.0.0` instead from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protobuf-cpp-3.0.0.tar.gz). Also in my case protobuf was in `/usr/include/google` so make sure to check there.

**Comment by [Yuuubc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40778/yuuubc/) on 2021-01-16**:
Thanks! It worked for me!

**Comment by [HarshalDawar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/70934/harshaldawar/) on 2022-01-25**:
Thanks, and relatedly:
For future reference, in case of having cartographer's system wide protoc/protobuf install: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2496#issuecomment-658545600